# Get Key reference form Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to write an App which throws out random usernames from my `Firebase Database`. In order to do this I need to get the reference key from each user, so that I can map it to the username in a different part of the app.

**Right the outcome looks like this:**

[image]
[image]

**This is what I would like to have (with the matching `Toast` of course):**

[image]

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseUser mCurrentUser;
    private DatabaseReference mUsersDatabase;
    private DatabaseReference mUsersDatabase1;
    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private String item;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_page_toolbar);
        mToolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        setSupportActionBar(this.mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("TestApp");

        mCurrentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        String current_uid = mCurrentUser.getUid(); 
        mUsersDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(current_uid);

        mUsersDatabase1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

    }
```

**Method to throw out random usernames**

```
public void getRandomUsernames(){

        mUsersDatabase1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                ArrayList<String> userlist = new ArrayList<String>();
                for(DataSnapshot dsp : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    userlist.add(String.valueOf(dsp.getValue()));
                }

                Object randomitem = userlist.get(new Random().nextInt(userlist.size()));
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), randomitem.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

}
```

Everything I tried didn't work out. Any suggestions is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [getKey](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot.html#getKey())()?

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    ArrayList<String> userlist = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> keylist = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(DataSnapshot dsp : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        userlist.add(String.valueOf(dsp.getValue()));
        keylist.add(dsp.getKey());
    }
    int randpos = new Random().nextInt(userlist.size());
    Object randomitem = userlist.get(randpos);
    String key = keylist.get(randpos);
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), randomitem.toString() + " key:" + key, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: I'm happy as it gets right now. Works like a charm. Thank u very much!!!

Comment: Great ! :-) Glad I could help you :)

Answer (score 0):

to get the key simply do this:

```
   DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");

reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
 @Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
for(DataSnapshot datas: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
   String keys=datas.getKey();
  }
 }
@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
  }
});
```

The for loop, will enable you to iterate inside the random key. This `String keys=datas.getKey();` will return the key.

> `public String getKey ()`
>
> the key name for the source location of this snapshot

more info here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot.html#getKey()